# Rebinding a detail view to a model with kendo UI

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a list view containing basic info about a set of tasks and I want to bind a detail view to the model object for an item when an item from the list is selected ...

http://jsfiddle.net/g2wYX/

I've been trying to use the change event of the grid ...

```
change: function (arg) {
    var grid = $("#taskGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
    kendo.bind("#taskDetail", selectedItem);
}
```

For some reason I can't seem to figure out the model binding on the detail view.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binding is just simple as binding to any of the View, the only difference is that you have to place the Detail template inside a **< scripts />** tag with type set as **text/x-kendo-template**. I have updated your fiddle example to what I have understood you require.

```
<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
```

and provide the detail template link to the Grid as below:

```
detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html()),
```

Let me know if the solution is not what you desired or you are confused in any code statement.

**[Question Fiddle Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/g2wYX/1/)**

---

**EDIT:**

Updated the fiddle Solution as per your requirement,have a look and let me if that is as per your requirement.

The only change that is required in your code is just change the **data-bind** from **value** to **html**

**[Updated Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/g2wYX/2/)**

Comment: I need the detail view outside the table, I had considered this approach but due to other requirements it doesn't quite fit. I suppose this could half fit the problem if i declare a detail template and render it inside a div but i was hoping to use unbind and bind to basically "reuse" 1 detail view.